# Delete xmlns="" from SOAP response in a VB.NET Web Service

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, soap, namespaces

im currently working in a Web Service that is made with vb.net. The problem is that im returning an xml documento for the WS reponse like this:
[WS Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsu3r.png)
(note the **mensaje** xml tag)

But when I call this service from soapUI or Postman the answer comes like this:
[Soap WS Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN3Xj.png)

It adds a xmlsn="" which I need to delete but I dont know how. Here is my code:

```
' Load and extract data from the input XML
oXMLDocument.LoadXml(Input)
sConvenio = GetSetNodeValue(oXMLDocument, "mensaje/encabezado/convenio", "", Nothing)
siden01 = Trim(GetSetNodeValue(oXMLDocument, "mensaje/identificador/iden01", "", Nothing))

' Check the length of a string
If Strings.Len(ConectaCompania(sConvenio)) = 36 Then
    ' Construct a SOAP request
    sTemp = "<!-- Query -->"
    sQuery = "<!-- SOAP request construction code -->"

    ' Send the SOAP request and receive a response
    sSOAPans = DISnode.Interact(sQuery)
    oXMLDoc.LoadXml(sSOAPans)

    ' Process the SOAP response and set values in the response XML
    If xmlNL.Count = 0 And oXMLDoc.InnerText <> "oRecordset0.00000000" Then
        ' Extract and set response tags
        GetSetNodeValue(oXMLDocument, "mensaje/encabezado/codigoRetorno", "000", Nothing)
        GetSetNodeValue(oXMLDocument, "mensaje/encabezado/mensajeRetorno", "CONSULTA EXITOSA", Nothing)
        
        ' Extract and set identifier and value tags (repeat for others)
        GetSetNodeValue(oXMLDocument, "mensaje/identificador/iden01", siden01, Nothing)
        ' ...
        
        ' Return the modified XML document
        Return oXMLDocument
    End If
End If
```

As you can see, Im not adding that xmlns="" so thats added by the soap response. How can I prevent this to happend?

Thank you!

I've tried returning a XNode object instead of XmlDocument and searching for xmlns="" inside of tags and remove it. Nothing with results.

Comment: Why do you care if it has `xmlns=""`? Do you just think it looks ugly, or do you want the content to be in the http://sebipagos.bi.com.gt/Consultar namespace, or what?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConsultarResponse` element is bound to a namespace and isn't using a namespace-prefix. Any descendant elements without a namespace-prefix would be in the http://sebipagos.bi.com.gt/Consultar namespace. So it needs `xmlns=""` to indicate that there is no namespace associated with `mensaje` element (and it's descendants) and they are NOT bound to the http://sebipagos.bi.com.gt/Consultar namespace.

If you don't want to see `xmlns=""` on the `mensaje` element, then you either need to have `ConsultartResponse` use a namespace prefix, or NOT be bound to a namespace.